# what is the advantages, disadvantages and issues when migrating database from oracle 11g to MySql 5.7?

Tags: oracle11g, database-migration, mysql-5.7

I am trying to migrate database from oracle 11g to MySql 5.7, after the migration what are the issues i might find ?. How triggers, sequences, privileges etc are supported ?. Any performance issues ?. I need to report these pros and cons before migrating from oracle to MySql. Please help me to report, i didn't find any solution in google related to this, anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the ANSI SQL standard every DBS has its own specialties.
All your Questions are so much depending on your specific DB structure, code and functions you've used, nobody can give you clear answer.

You can run in all the Problems you are asking or into none of them.

If your current Oracle DB application is 100% ANSI SQL it should at least run, but i doubt it will be 100% ANSI SQL.

The only possible answer is try it, see what Problems you are facing and then decide if you want to do it or not.

Comment: I need to report in general what are the disadvantages when migration from oracle to mysql ?. Please suggest.

Comment: generally there are some features missing or different in mysql. maybe this link is useful for you, there is a comparison of datatypes and functions etc. between oracle and mysql http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql